# Really basic question about the Taylor expansion of a CDF

Tags: probability-distributions, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am sorry for such a basic question... but I want to try to do a Taylor expansion on my function, which is a CDF defined over 0-1.  However, when I expand around 0, which is what I read is typical, then everything cancels out, because all the derivatives at 0 are going to be 0.  Clearly, I am missing something obvious....  can anyone point it out for me?  I have never done this before and am reading up on Internet sites, but none seem to explain this basic of a point.  Am I misunderstanding the whole idea of a Taylor expansion?  Are you only allowed to use some values for $a$ (where $a$ is the constant you are expanding around?

Comment: We could be a bit more helpful if you'd say what your CDF is...

Comment: @J.M.  The function in question is $(1-(1-x)^n)^n$  But wouldn't the derivative of all CDFs defined over 0 to 1 be 0 at 0?

Comment: @testing, that's a polynomial -- it _can't_ have all zero derivatives. Its leading term is $x^{n^2}$, so the $n^2$th derivative at 0 is $n^2!$. Probably you're making some mistake while differentiating it. Could you elaborate on your reasoning?

Comment: @Henning:  I wasn't doing more than a couple differentiations, I was more thinking about the nature of the cdf/pdf and assuming they would always have a 0 derivative at 0.  I think I was just really wrong.  Thanks for helping to clear it up...

Comment: It is crucial that you specified that $f$ was defined only for $f\in[0,1]$. That allows $f(0)=0, f'(0)>0$ without $f$ ever needing to be negative (which doesn't make sense for a cdf). If instead you had said that $f$ is defined on $\mathbb R$ but $f(x)=0$ when $x<0$, then you're right that it couldn't have any nonzero derivatives. However, then most likely it wouldn't be differentiable arbitrary many times _at all_, and so it wouldn't have any Taylor series at 0, not even the zero one.

Comment: For your particular function, the first $n$ derivatives are going to be 0, because $1-(1-x)^n$ has zero constant term, and so $(1-(1-x)^n)^n = x^n p(x)^n$ for some polynomial $p$.

Comment: @Henning:  That is so, so helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have discovered that not all functions are equal to their Taylor expansions. That's just a fact of life.

Functions that *are* equal to their Taylor expansion are called *analytic*. In practice, most functions you can write down explicitly without resorting to case analysis are analytic, but arbitrary functions don't have to be.

A standard example of a non-analytic function is
$$f(x) = \cases{0 & \text{when }x=0 \\ e^{-1/x^2} & \text{otherwise}}$$

Comment: You intended $\exp(-x^{-2})$ I presume?

Comment: @J.M., yes. I copied from a one-sided example without thinking enough.